# the idea of wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question about generating a "wordpress shortcode like" code in my website. Does somebody know how they did the shortcode in wordpress? I have an idea of having the contents inside a string variable then  check if the string has my listed shortcode for example:

```
$x = "there should be a shortcode here [theshortcode]";
//if there is a match
//update the x string add the return of the shortcode [the shortcode]
//then display it using echo
```

Is this correct concept or does anyone know how the concept behind wordpress shortcode?

(note: I am not using wordpress. I am developing my own website that uses the shortcode concept of wordpress)

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I'm asking about how they implemented shortcode in php and not asking how to use wordpress shortcodes. I'm trying to develop a website that uses shortcodes and not using wordpress

Comment: o well then please update your question as what you just said and what you posted is a completely different question.

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L228 I believe this is what you want as it shows of how they currently parse for the shortcode and on this line they implement the calling function https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L277

Answer (score 3):

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L228 includes the code that is used to parse the shortcode...

```
function get_shortcode_regex() {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    $tagnames = array_keys($shortcode_tags);
    $tagregexp = join( '|', array_map('preg_quote', $tagnames) );

    // WARNING! Do not change this regex without changing do_shortcode_tag() and strip_shortcode_tag()
    // Also, see shortcode_unautop() and shortcode.js.
    return
          '\\['                              // Opening bracket
        . '(\\[?)'                           // 1: Optional second opening bracket for escaping shortcodes: [[tag]]
        . "($tagregexp)"                     // 2: Shortcode name
        . '(?![\\w-])'                       // Not followed by word character or hyphen
        . '('                                // 3: Unroll the loop: Inside the opening shortcode tag
        .     '[^\\]\\/]*'                   // Not a closing bracket or forward slash
        .     '(?:'
        .         '\\/(?!\\])'               // A forward slash not followed by a closing bracket
        .         '[^\\]\\/]*'               // Not a closing bracket or forward slash
        .     ')*?'
        . ')'
        . '(?:'
        .     '(\\/)'                        // 4: Self closing tag ...
        .     '\\]'                          // ... and closing bracket
        . '|'
        .     '\\]'                          // Closing bracket
        .     '(?:'
        .         '('                        // 5: Unroll the loop: Optionally, anything between the opening and closing shortcode tags
        .             '[^\\[]*+'             // Not an opening bracket
        .             '(?:'
        .                 '\\[(?!\\/\\2\\])' // An opening bracket not followed by the closing shortcode tag
        .                 '[^\\[]*+'         // Not an opening bracket
        .             ')*+'
        .         ')'
        .         '\\[\\/\\2\\]'             // Closing shortcode tag
        .     ')?'
        . ')'
        . '(\\]?)';                          // 6: Optional second closing brocket for escaping shortcodes: [[tag]]
}
```

I believe this is what you want as it shows of how they currently parse for the shortcode and on this line they implement the calling function https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L277...

```
function do_shortcode_tag( $m ) {
    global $shortcode_tags;

    // allow [[foo]] syntax for escaping a tag
    if ( $m[1] == '[' && $m[6] == ']' ) {
        return substr($m[0], 1, -1);
    }

    $tag = $m[2];
    $attr = shortcode_parse_atts( $m[3] );

    if ( isset( $m[5] ) ) {
        // enclosing tag - extra parameter
        return $m[1] . call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[$tag], $attr, $m[5], $tag ) . $m[6];
    } else {
        // self-closing tag
        return $m[1] . call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[$tag], $attr, null,  $tag ) . $m[6];
    }
}
```

to be honest i would just download a copy of wordpress and steal the wp-includes/shortcodes.php file and save yourself the hassle or re-implementing this.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's basically the same as yours. And I voted your answer because I think it's the right answer for the question. I don't understand the downvote..